# Replying to a message in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

i am trying to develop a messaging system in my laravel app, i have managed to send a message to the user and retrieve them in the inbox section of my blade view. so my wonder is, how exactly am i going to reply a message that is in the inbox??

here is how i have them in the mail.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-inbox table-hover">
      @foreach($messages as $meso => $message)
        <tbody>
           <tr class="unread">
             <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
             </td>
             <td class="inbox-small-cells"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
             <td class="view-message dont-show">{{ $message->sent_to_id }}</td>
             <td class="view-message dont-show">{{ $message->name }}</td>
             <td class="view-message dont-show">{{ $message->subject }}</td>
             <td class="view-message view-message"><p>{{ $message->body }}</p></td>
             <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></td>
             <td class="view-message text-right">{{ $message->created_at }}</td>
             <td class="view-message dont-show"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#squarespaceModal" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Reply</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     @endforeach
 </table>
```

and my User Model is:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function sendMessageTo($recipient, $message, $subject)
    {

        Auth::user()->sendMessageTo($request->recipient, $request->subject, $request->body);

    }


    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    // A user can send a message
    public function sent()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'sender_id');
    }

    // A user can also receive a message
    public function received()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'sent_to_id');
    }
    public function message()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Message::class);
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}


}
```

**and here goes my Message model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body', 'subject', 'sent_to_id', 'sender_id'];

    // A message belongs to a sender
    public function sender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sender_id');
    }

    // A message also belongs to a receiver    
    public function receiver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sent_to_id');
    }
    public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function message()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Message::class);
}
```

}
My MessageController

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request)
    {
        // Do the validation...

        // Send the message from the current user to the user with ID of 1,
        // You probably always want the current logged-in user as the sender.
        // We talk about the recipient later...
        //
        Auth::user()->sent()->create([
            'body'       => $request->body,
            'subject'    => $request->subject,
            'sent_to_id' => $request->recipient,
        ]);   
$messages = Message::where('sent_to_id', '=', Auth::user()->name)->get();



$users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get()->pluck('name', 'id');


            return view('mail')->with(compact('messages', 'users'));

   }
```

Any tips of how to reply to this messages

Comment: @MirzaObaid any ideas on this

Comment: This all depends on what type of messaging system you intend to build. If it is just single messages with no need of threaded messaging then you can simply do the same as you are now, just update the user id you are sending to. Should you however wish to have threaded messaging then you need at least 1 pivot table. `conversation`, `conversation_participants`, `conversation_messages`. Both participants and messages have a foreign key to conversation. Conversastion meta data is stored in conversation, messages in messages and participants has the user_id, last_read etc in it.

Comment: @Ian my main problem now is how to pick the details of the message am replying to because currently the details if one message is duplicated in every message perhaps my query is wrong "$messages = Message::where('sent_to_id', '=', Auth::user()->name)->get();
". this fills up the inbox, but when i click reply on a message i get the values of the first message on the table